# VB.net CMYK Image saving

Tags: vb.net, image, colors

I have an issue where i have 4 RGB Bitmaps.
Each bitmap contains an image of a single colour
for example
image 1 = Cyan image
image 2 = Magenta image
image 3 - Yellow image
image 4 = black image

I need to find a way to combine the colour data from each image and save as a CMYK formatted file, preferably TIF.

The idea i have had is to create a tiff file at runtime using the CMYK data obtainable from the above images, but the image structure is escaping me.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

If you can install ImageMagick, it is easy:

```
convert cyan.bmp magenta.bmp yellow.bmp black.bmp -set colorspace CMYK -combine combined.tif
```

You can either shell out (using `system()` and the above command), or link with any of the ImageMagick bindings which include Perl, C/C++, python, php, .Net etc.

It is available, for free, [here](http://www.imagemagick.org).

Comment: Thankyou Does this create a sinlge page tiff file or multipage tiff ?

Comment: It creates a single TIFF image.